# Typescript extend the class of an imported component

Tags: typescript

I am using this component: https://github.com/meliorence/react-native-snap-carousel
The component is using FlatList, so I can use methods in it that derive from FlatList, such as onEndReached:

```
import BottomCarousel from 'react-native-snap-carousel';

<BottomCarousel
  onEndReached={loadMore} // << This gives a TS error
  ...
```

However, the library does not extend the typescript definition of those methods, so I'm getting an error `Property 'onEndReached' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes &...`

How can I include those TS definitions in the component I load in the View without touching the original component?

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed the types for the lirbrary?
`$ npm install --save @types/react-native-snap-carousel`